# Spring FTP issue when sending file TO FTP

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I'm trying to send a file to a FTP.

I noticed that using a command prompt everything is ok if I do this:

```
put test.txt 'MY_FILE_NAME_IN_FTP_HERE'
```

But, trying to send the file using my Spring I'm getting this:

> exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to write to 'MY_FILE_NAME_IN_FTP_HERE'. Server replied with: 554 Requested action not taken: GDG name conversion failed.

My handler is like (this is like the outbound channel adapter if you want to see this as a xml):

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toFtpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() throws IOException {
    FileTransferringMessageHandler handler = new FileTransferringMessageHandler(ftpSessionFactory());        

    final String fileNameExpression = MY_FILE_NAME_IN_FTP_HERE
    //TODO: Need to check how should be the actual remote directory expression. It is mandatory in the SessionFactory.
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression(""));        
    handler.setUseTemporaryFileName(false);
    handler.setFileNameGenerator(new FileNameGenerator() {
        public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
             return fileNameExpression;
        }
    });
    return handler;
}
```

My question is, why am I missing in my sessionFactory

Comment: Try to use ` handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(new LiteralExpression("/"));` or what is appropriate for your user. You really have a problem with remote directory: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21541374

Comment: I've already tried to use ("/"). I'm trying to figure out why the command prompt works fine but not Spring nor Filezilla (for instance).

Comment: Compare the `workingDirectory` there. Your prompt might choose a different dir, not like it is by default for your user.

Answer (score 0):

After having added `ftpSessionFactory.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);` To my session Factory, the problem has gone.

So My new Sessiong Factory config is:

```
    @Bean
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() throws IOException {
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftpSessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();

    ftpSessionFactory.setHost(host);
    ftpSessionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));
    ftpSessionFactory.setUsername(username);
    ftpSessionFactory.setPassword(password);
    ftpSessionFactory.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(ftpSessionFactory);        
}
```